# Грядущее обновление дизайна

Tags: обсуждение, новости, design

В течение ближайших месяцев на нашем и всех других сайтах сети Stack Exchange будет изменен дизайн. В связи с этим предлагаю познакомиться с основными пунктами обновления и обсудить их:

### Навигация – слева

[image: примерный внешний вид панели навигации слева]
Теперь разделы «Вопросы», «Метки» и «Участники» будут располагаться слева, а не сверху (как в текущей версии сайта).

### Отзывчивый дизайн

У каждого пользователя есть свои предпочтения, связанные с размером окна браузера: кто-то считает, что наиболее удобен полноэкранный режим, а кто-то, наоборот, любит окна разных размеров. С введением отзывчивого дизайна внешний вид сайта будет автоматически адаптироваться под любой размер окна браузера. [Вот как это работает.](https://i.imgur.com/DuOp1WV.gifv)

### Новое оформление

[image]
Предполагается, что большинство сайтов сети Stack Exchange получат собственное оформление, особенностью которого будет, например, специальная цветовая гамма. Тем не менее оно будет основываться на общем шаблоне, в связи с чем уровень «индивидуализации» каждого сайта будет ограничен.

---

### Когда ждать обновления

Скорее всего, описанные выше изменения будут устанавливаться на наш сайт в порядке, сходном с расположением пунктов в этой статье, и финальную версию нового дизайна мы получим ближе к сентябрю.

**Предлагаю обсудить будущие нововведения!**

*Подробнее (на английском) – [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/379531).*

Answer (score 2):

А в чём смысл обсуждения? Мы можем на что-то повлиять?

Единственная претензия к текущему дизайну у меня такая: шапка, на которой размещены названия разделов "Вопросы, Метки, Участники, ..." занимает в 2 или 3 раза больше места по вертикали, чем следовало бы, отбирая это пространство у функционально полезной части дизайна.

В предлагаемой версии существенно лучше, насколько я могу судить по картинке, но это всё "компенсируется" разделом "Текущие вопросы" — этот раздел займёт в 2 раза больше места по вертикали, чем сейчас.

Простой способ исправить этот недостаток: перенести кнопку "Задать вопрос" на своё нынешнее место -- в верхнюю шапку.

Comment: В наших силах повлиять на то, какой окажется финальная версия. Большое спасибо за то, что вы откликнулись! Кажется, о проблеме нерационально используемого места уже написали на англоязычном сайте, но я на всякий случай передам ваше предложение снова.

Answer (score 1):

Есть проблемы с переводом меню и названий разделов на русский язык. Например, в английской версии *unanswered* и *no answer* имеют разный смысл, а на русский переводятся одинаково.